# CouchDb Crashes with no reason in the crash report

Tags: erlang, couchdb, mochiweb

CouchDb keeps crashing and outputs the following log. I tried searching the CouchDb guides as to what the crash reason is, but I couldn't find anything. It appears that the reason is a `badmatch` but I am not sure what the bad match would be. Any idea on what error the crash report refers to?  I am running the latest version of Couch on Windows.

```
[Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:09:38 GMT] [error] [<0.10713.9>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
                       {<0.10713.9>,crash_report,
                        [[{initial_call,
                           {mochiweb_acceptor,init,
                            ['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3']}},
                          {pid,<0.10713.9>},
                          {registered_name,[]},
                          {error_info,
                           {error,
                            {badmatch,{error,einval}},
                            [{mochiweb_http,new_request,3,
                              [{file,
                                "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~1.0/src/mochiweb/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                               {line,133}]},
                             {mochiweb_http,handle_invalid_request,3,
                              [{file,
                                "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~1.0/src/mochiweb/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                               {line,127}]},
                             {mochiweb_http,handle_invalid_request,1,
                              [{file,
                                "c:/cygwin/relax/APACHE~1.0/src/mochiweb/mochiweb_http.erl"},
                               {line,122}]},
                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                              [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                          {ancestors,
                           [couch_httpd,couch_secondary_services,
                            couch_server_sup,<0.35.0>]},
                          {messages,[{tcp_closed,#Port<0.42313>}]},
                          {links,[<0.111.0>]},
                          {dictionary,
                           [{couch_rewrite_count,0},{jsonp,no_jsonp}]},
                          {trap_exit,false},
                          {status,running},
                          {heap_size,2586},
                          {stack_size,27},
                          {reductions,23231254}],
                         []]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/201212.mbox/%3CCAHZBNKbhXinyJzbTZ14Ddi9_2jTu=9QjMFjSS+36_vnM80PPCw@mail.gmail.com%3E) could help you.
But it looks like it's an old bug, already solved in Mochiweb. Are you running the latest version of CouchDb?

Comment: Yep I am running v1.5.0

Comment: Couch is using mochiweb v1.4.0, which is outdated (3 years old). Do you happen to know if the next latest release of Couch will contain a newer version of mochiweb?

Comment: I downgraded the version to 1.5.0_R14B04, and that fixed the crash.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I'm sorry, I don't know about a new version Mochiweb. You should ask to the CouchDB developers.